# Conversions in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsoutputstream

I know this question must have been asked before in another form. I am trying to write to an `NSOutputStream` a message I am composing from different things from my view.

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: UIButton!) {

    var msg = self.messageText.text as String!
    var response = "msgtouser:" + self.nameofSender + ":" + nameofReceiver + ":" + self.messageText.text
    var res : Int

    self.outputStream.write(response, maxLength :response.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding))
}
```

I get an error when I try to make the reponse by concatenating multiple strings. The error  I am getting is saying that String is not convertible to `UInt8` when I try to concatenate the `self.messageText.text`.

The same thing happens when I try to add the response variable

Comment: I've noticed that Swift loves to give the UInt8 error whenever a conversion fails, regardless of the actual types involved.  Are you sure that all the properties are Strings?  What happens if you explicitly type `var response: String`?

Comment: Yes,this solves it but now the <b> : </b> fails

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by <b> : </b>.  If the new problem is to do with different code, it might be best to open a new question?  Unless I'm missing something obvious, I don't see anything like that here.

Comment: Sorry i meant to put the ":" in bold...I fixed these issues by making  the variables with "!"

Comment: @tudoricc Text here uses [Markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). For bold, surround the **item** with double asterisks, like `**this**`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.fome reason i thought it was with the HTML tagging.Sorry then

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to the "swift way". It may help as stated in the documentation. ex:

```
    let multiplier = 3
    let message = "\(multiplier) times 2.5 is \(Double(multiplier) * 2.5)"
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To put my comment here for future readers:

As of the current beta, the Swift compiler seems to have issues implicitly typing certain expressions.

In order to avoid this, you can add an explicit type to the result variable.
This will cause any operators in that expression (eg, the addition ones in this question) to behave more sanely.

So, in the code above, we simply need to do:

```
var response: String = ...
```